# How to get file path to show on Netbeans tab

Tags: file, netbeans, path

I wanted to know if anyone knew how to get the full file path of a file to show on a Netbeans tab like the image attached: 
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tools->Options->Tab Appearance->Tab Document Tabs->Show full file path.
M.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually found it here:`Tools ->Options->Appearance->Document Tabs-> Show full path checkmark` . but you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

On **Netbeans IDE 8.2** it differs slightly:

**Tools -> Options -> Appearance -> Document Tabs -> Show full file path**